# A handyman abandoned his tools at our place, won't answer calls

Tags: plumbing, code-compliance, safety

I am not sure if this is the right place for this question, but a handyman we hired (Massachusetts area) has left his tools, including a blow torch, at our place after a botched bathroom tub repair. His tools have been at our house for over a month now, and he won't pick up calls or answer messages anymore. We were worried he might have COVID or was maybe unwell- he did pick up the phone once, he said he would be collecting his tools soon. That was three weeks ago.

Maybe just being paranoid, but first: is there any danger of his blow torch exploding for any reason? We have just left all his things untouched, so it's just sitting there in his tool bag without any chance (hopefully) of getting direct heat or getting punctured. We are pretty sure he was not licensed to use that blow torch as he is a handyman, and not a licensed plumber.

Secondly: I am just perplexed by this mystery-why has this man left the tools of his trade at our place for over a month? Are the tools implicated in a crime or something? What is the recourse for my family here? Is he waiting for us to get tired, throw them out and bill us for new ones? Anyone deal with something like this?

Comment: If you can reach him via email or text, do so and keep the screenshots indicating that you were trying to get his tools back to him. And I agree with the answer: the guy's a flake. (And probably embarrassed that he made a mess.)

Comment: Very unusual to leave tools behind for long. Perhaps he is unwell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a license to operate a plumbing torch. There's no danger of it spontaneously exploding if you keep it away from heat sources and open flames.

He hasn't dealt with you punctually because he's an unreliable flake. Look up laws for abandoned property in your locality.

Eventually his tools become your tools.

Comment: as it has a gas bottle the blow torch should be stored in a well ventilated location and away from ignition sources, but there is very little risk.

Comment: While you don't need a license to operate a torch, given it's Massachusetts you probably DO need a plumbing license to be doing plumbing on a house you don't own (heck, they even call out things they won't let you do in your own house, and have some godawful bizzare idiocy enshrined in law, such as using three valves to bypass a water softener that can be operated improperly rather than a standard bypass valve that's either opened or bypassed.)

Comment: Thanks- very informative

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the propane torch:  virtually no risk.  They can sit there forever with no impact unless you subject it to fire or similar.

Regarding the property:  Evidently it is very painful in Massachusetts for his property to legally become yours.  https://law.justia.com/codes/massachusetts/2006/gl-pt2-toc/gl-200a-toc.html  It's a good idea to have written evidence of you trying to contact him for a couple of months, and even then you're not totally off the hook.  But you should get legal advice only from an attorney licensed in your state.